# jQuery (Javascript) parse document name from pathname

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For a url like `example.com/this/is/my/path.html`

`var pageName = $(location).attr('pathname')`

assigns the following result to the variable.

`this/is/my/path.html`

My question: How could I further parse `pageName` to produce only `path.html`?

Or, is there another `.attr()` jQuery reference that will only give you that info?

Comment: You really don't need an 80kb library in order to do `location.pathname.split("/").pop()`

Comment: Thanks for the reminder @BenjaminGruenbaum . Should have mention that I'm using jQuery for other things as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on the responses below, I found that:

`var pageName = $(location).attr('pathname').split('/').pop();`

...got me the result that I was looking for.

Comment: Tip (downvotes not from me): When you write an answer make sure it IS an answer. You just ask a new question, and the "answer" parts are just copied from others. You can update your own question instead.

Comment: You clearly don't understand how to use this website properly. Try giving this a read: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Thanks to you both. I've looked at the tour @NickDugger thanks. And I do appreciate the helpfulness of the answers, despite the (snarky?) rhetoric.

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
var theUrl = $(this).attr('href');
var index = theUrl.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
var filename = theUrl.substr(index);
console.log( 'link file name is '+filename );
```

Comment: upvoting this for `$(this).attr("href")`, although no link tags are mentioned at all this solution is superior since it uses jQuery which is great and does all things.